# Entity framework one to many

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework and have the following classes

```
class Student
{
 [Key]
 public virtual int StudentID {get; set;}
 public virtual string StudentName {get; set;}
 public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes {get; set;}
}
class Note
{
 [Key]
 public virtual int NoteID {get; set;}
 public virtual int StudentID {get; set;}
 public virtual string Message {get; set;}
}
class StudentDBContext:DbContext
{
 public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
 public DbSet<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}
```

So to summarize, I have a class of students who can each have many notes. Now, I want to use Linq to retrieve and display all the notes for a particular student. So I try

```
using (StudentDBContext a = new StudentDBContext())
{
 var b = from c in a.Student
         where c.StudentID == 1001
         select c;

 var currStudent = b.FirstOrDefault();
 Console.WriteLine(currStudent.StudentName);

  //display all the messages of the current student
  foreach (var currNote in currStudent.Notes)
  Console.WriteLine(currNote.Message);
}
```

In the above code, my foreach block always fails because Student.Notes is always null. Am I missing some step in initializing Student.Notes and populating it from the database?

Comment: Sure that Student.Notes is null and not Student?

Comment: @archil yes, I can successfully print out the student name. I run into problems only when I try to access the ICollection<Note> Notes

Comment: Did you disable lazy loading or proxy creation in the `StudentDBContext` constructor?

Comment: Don't you need to define the relation in for example the OnModelCreating method like in this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/23/associations-in-ef-code-first-ctp5-part-3-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx)

Comment: @Slauma - On your suggestion, I tried disabling lazy loading by setting

this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

but still have no luck

Comment: It wasn't a suggestion, only a question :) You should NOT disable lazy loading and you should NOT disable proxy creation, otherwise `currStudent.Notes` will be `null` in your code example.

Comment: Your code looks good, are you sure there are definitely some notes associated with the student. Try checking your database

Comment: shouldn't your notes class have a student property ? like public virtual Student student {get; set;} and i dont think you need the virtual keyword infront of the NoteID  and StudentID properties

Comment: There's a couple spelling mistakes in your code, so I'm assuming this isn't copy-and-paste. For instance, should be `a.Students` with an 's', along with the virtual/int stuff @marvc1 pointed out.  Is there something else relevant to the above code?

Comment: This code, with spelling mistakes and `int` fixed, compiles and runs fine in a console app with EF installed.

Comment: And the `ICollection<Note> Notes` is REALLY `virtual`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
using (StudentDBContext a = new StudentDBContext())
{
   var b = ((from c in a.Student
           join b in a.Notes on b.StudentId equals c.StudentId into sNotes
                 from notes in sNotes.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where c.StudentId==1001
           select c).SingleOrDefault();
   if (b != null )
     ...
}
```

Be aware of the fact that Entity Framework will do a lazy load of your data.  So if you don't do something to populate it then you will not get it.  There are other ways of doing it but among other things this query clearly documents that you are wanting both the student and notes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot accept two answers. This answer by @SASS_Shooter is correct because the explicit query requesting for data from the Notes is what I needed to force the ICollection<Note> to be populated.
tschmit007 - Your answer was also relevant as it helped me identify other errors in my code

Comment: @curiouspanda and SASS_Shooter: You can simplify this: `a.Student.Include(s => s.Notes).SingleOrDefault(s => s.StudentID == 1001);`. That's more the EF way instead of using a manual join. It all doesn't explain though why the lazy loading in the question doesn't work.

Comment: @Slauma - Thank you! That is a beautiful and elegant line of code that works too!

Answer (score 3):

Your class Student and Note should be public.

The following code runs:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        using ( StudentDBContext efc = new StudentDBContext()) {
            foreach (var v in efc.Students) {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", v.StudentName);
                foreach (var vv in v.Notes) {
                    Console.WriteLine("    {0}", vv.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Student {
    public Student() {
        //Notes = new List<Note>();
    }
     [Key]
     public int StudentID {get; set;}
     public virtual string StudentName {get; set;}
     public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes {get; set;}
}
public class Note {
 [Key]
 public int NoteID {get; set;}
 public int StudentID {get; set;}
 public string Message {get; set;}
}
class StudentDBContext:DbContext {
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Note> Notes { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: Your answer helped me fix a couple of bugs in my code but since I can select only one answer, I have to pick SASS_Shooter's since it fixed my original problem with the ICollection not being populated

Comment: @curiouspanda: Why didn't this answer fix your problem? The key is that your classes **must** be public in order to get lazy loading working (and your code relies in lazy loading). Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057.aspx (applies to change tracking proxies and lazy loading as well): "*A custom data class must be declared with* **public** *access"*

Comment: reward who you want but... the double loop in Main illustrates that ICollection is populated by lazy loading, that is inside the using.

Comment: @tschmit007 - I wish stack overflow allowed me to pick more than one answer. Your answer had to be combined with the SASS_Shooter's to fix my code. I just picked the answer that I thought would help more people coming to this page. :(

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be virtual.

```
public virtual NoteID {get; set;}
```

It should be an integer:

```
public int NoteID {get; set;}
```

Comment: Yeah, that wouldn't compile without that. The code mustn't have been copied and pasted. There's likely something more going on here.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the error in my original post. I must have messed up while trying to get the formatting right for posting it here